# C++ template argument inference

Tags: c++, templates, generics

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

template<class InputIterator>
typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type
sumRange(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
    // ignore validate [start, last)
    typedef typename __iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type value_type;
    value_type sum = *first++;
    while (first != last) {
        sum = sum + *first++;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    array<int, 3> a{4, 5, 6};
    cout << sumRange(a.begin(), a.end()) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

why the function `sumRange` can not apply to built-in type such as `int*` ?

But the STL algorithm `accumulate` work.

The error information is:

```
main.cpp:29:67: error: no type named 'value_type' in 'struct std::__iterator_traits<int*, void>'
     typedef typename __iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type value_type;
```

Comment: Why are you using `__iterator_traits` and not `std::iterator_traits`?

Answer (score 2):

For built-in types such as `int[]`, you need to use `std::begin(a)` and `std::end(a)` on these types, also - as NathanOliver wrote - `std::iterator_traits<>` instead of the implementation detail `__iterator_traits<>`.

`std::begin()` and `std::end()` works for std containers as well (in which case, it delegates to the member functions `begin()` and `end()`, respectively), so these are more generic and thus preferred. It's also what range-based `for` uses.

Comment: Why do they need to use `std::being` and `std::end`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Question is not in example code but after it: OP wants to use it for `int*` and `int*` does not have a member function `begin()` or `end()`. (Edited the response to make it clear.)

Comment: The `int*` is coming from `a.begin()` and `a.end()` as `std::array` just uses a pointer for the iterator type.  Code compiles fine when using `std::iterator_traits`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d7dede174f41675

Comment: @NathanOliver Please read OP's _question_, not the _code_. OP wants `int a[] = {4, 5, 6};` instead of `std::array<int, 3> a = {4, 5, 6};`.